# How do I fix an "ambiguous" function call?

Tags: c++, ambiguous-call

I'm working on a C++ program for class, and my compiler is complaining about an "ambiguous" function call. I suspect that this is because there are several functions defined with different parameters.

How can I tell the compiler which one I want? Aside from a case-specific fix, is there a general rule, such as typecasting, which might solve these kinds of problems?

**Edit:**

In my case, I tried calling `abs()` inside of a `cout` statement, passing in two `double`s.

`cout << "Amount is:" << abs(amountOrdered-amountPaid);`

**Edit2:**

I'm including these three headers:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;
```

**Edit3:**

I've finished the program without this code, but in the interest of following through with this question, I've reproduced the problem. The verbatim error is:

> Call to 'abs' is ambiguous.

The compiler offers three versions of `abs`, each taking a different datatype as a parameter.

Comment: Would you please show an example from your code?

Comment: It really depends on the situation. You need to post the code and if the compiler error includes which functions are candidates (recent GCCs do) that helps as well.

Comment: Also good would be which headers are included.

Comment: What is the _verbatim_ error you get?

Comment: @Moshe: Perhaps you could include the rest of the message. You said "The compiler offers three versions of `abs`", but you haven't shown what those messages are.

Comment: In an unrelated case, it turned out it was possible to fix "Call to member function ... is ambiguous" using `std::enable_if_t<std::is_pointer<T>::value, ...` This was where behaviour needed to be different for pointers/nonpointers and the respective overloads were not being matched intuitively.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

What's happened is that you've included `<cstdlib>` (indirectly, since it's included by `iostream`) along with `using namespace std;`. This header declares two functions in `std` with the name `abs()`. One takes and returns `long long`, and the other returns `long`. Plus, there's the one in the global namespace (that returns `int`) that comes from `<stdlib.h>`.

To fix: well, the `abs()` that takes double is in `<cmath>`, and that will actually give you the answer you want!

Comment: TL;DR: avoid `using namespace`.

Comment: @MatthieuM., I have seen this (sematic) error even when using `std::abs()` in iOS SDK. The error got removed when I removed `std::` and used just `abs()`.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is more due to automatic numeric type conversion.

Answer (score 5):

The `abs` function included by `<cstdlib>` is overloaded for `int` and `long` and `long long`. Since you give a `double` as the argument, the compiler does not have an exact fit, so it tries to convert the `double` to a type that `abs` accepts, but it does not know if it should try to convert it to `int`, `long`, or `long long`, hence it's ambiguous.

But you probably really want the `abs` that takes a `double` and returns a `double`. For this you need to include `<cmath>`. Since the `double` argument matches exactly, the compiler will not complain.

It seems that `<cstdlib>` gets included automatically when you include the other headers which should not happen. The compiler should have given `error: ‘abs’ was not declared in this scope` or something similar.

Comment: `abs` isn't a function template. Giving a template argument won't work. A `static_cast<foo>(bar)` would compile (but still give a wrong answer)

Comment: @mkb - Thanks, I forgot they are simply overloads not template functions specializations. Edited that part out.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `fabs` defined in `<cmath>`. It takes `float`, `double` and `long double` as arguments. `abs` is defined both in `<cmath>` and `<cstdlib>`. The difference is `abs(int)`, `abs(long)` and `abs(long long)` are defined in `<cstdlib>` while other versions are defined in `<cmath>`.

Comment: A common solution to fix this kind of error is use C++ version of the library instead of standard C library, ex: cstdio instead of stdio.h. The C++ libs have name with prefix 'c' and no '.h'

Answer (score -3):

Not sure why this isn't calling the int version of abs but you could try type casting the expression (amountOrdered - amountPaid) as int i.e.

```
cout <<"Amount is: "<< abs( (int)(amountOrdered - amountPaint) );
```

Comment: "Not sure why this isn't calling the int version of abs" Could it be cause `amountOrdered` and `amountPaid` are doubles?

Comment: You are correct not sure what I was thinking ! @OP compiler is confused  which version to call (long or double) because it not sure if it needs to typecast to long or int from double. Mr .R.Martinho - I guess my solution will help the compiler deciding which version to call. So I somewhat stand correct :)