# Is this correct way to fix ambiguous function call

Tags: c++

I have code like this:

```
#include <cstdio>

void test(size_t const pos){
    printf("size_t\n");
}

void test(const void *ptr){
    printf("ptr\n");
}

//void test(int const pos){
//  printf("int\n");
//}

int main(){
    size_t x = 0;

    test(x);
    test(nullptr);
    test(&x);
//  test(0);
// some more that fail, but I do not care too much about them:
//  test(0U);
//  test(0L);
//  test(NULL);
}
```

When I un-comment `test(0);` it does not compile, because the compiler does not know how to convert '0'.

If I introduce 'int' overload, everything compiles again.

Is this correct way to avoid ambiguous function call?

**UPDATE**

Correct would mean - I want not to call pointer overload, except in case argument is pointer or `nullptr` is passed.

I am aware that current "setup" fails with `0U`, `0L`, `NULL`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I fix an "ambiguous" function call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7549874/how-do-i-fix-an-ambiguous-function-call)

Comment: Well... It depends on what result are you expecting.

Comment: Well, since this resolved the compilation error, I don't know of any better definition of "correct".

Comment: Using a cast..?

Comment: "correct" really depends on what you want to do. 0 is an int **without** an implicit conversion so the `int` one will be taken if available. On the other cases both of them take 0 **after** an implicit conversion but none-has priority. So it's ambiguous. You can "choose" which implementation to take by using a cast (explicit conversion).

Comment: @Jezor - is is not a duplicate

Comment: It is not a duplicate but it is Primarily Opinion Based.  It really depends how you want to handle the input like Hayt stated.

Comment: `test(0u);` actually fail to compile. `test(0l);` fails as well. infamous `test(NULL);` fails too. I need to do overload for each type. However I want to handle 0 only.

Comment: The above post describes no criteria to judge what is "correct", what is left is opinion.  VTC as opinion based question without clarification.  What is "correct" requires opinion, or information not presented.  Attempts to ask for clarification in comments have failed to generate useful information.  "Is not a duplicate" and "I want to handle 0" are not useful.

Comment: What do you want to happen when `0`, `0U`, `0L` are entered?

Comment: @Nick You can cast to a `void*` like, `test((void*)0)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The literal `0` has type `int`. If there is a `test(int)` overload, then this will be called, because no conversion is required. Easy.

If there is no `test(int)` available, then the compiler will see whether the argument can be converted to either `size_t` or `void*` to satisfy the other overloads. A literal `0` can be implicitly converted to either type, and the conversion rules don't tell it to prefer either one, so the result is ambiguous.

In order to specify that you want `test(size_t)` called, you'll need to explicitly create a `0` of type `size_t`, i.e.

```
test(size_t{0});
```

Comment: An `int` cannot be implicitly converted to `void*`. `0` is special.

Comment: @Barry Quite right, thanks. Edited.

Comment: @Barry exactly what I ment

Comment: You could even mention that starting with C++17, there is a `std::size_t` literal: `test(0z);`

Comment: @Rakete1111 I wasn't aware of that, thanks!